# Multiple distros crash and reboot when trying to resume from sleep/suspend on laptop

Tags: kernel, nvidia, suspend, laptop

Gigabyte Aorus 15 XE4. Nvidia RTX 3070ti. After multiple attempts, this doesn't seem to be related to Nvidia Drivers or intel/nvidia optimus like I thought based on many people with a similar issue. (also please let me know if this question would be better somewhere else - thanks)

Laptop *appears* to suspend fine as the breathing suspend led is active. Then upon opening or pressing power to wake, keyboard lights up and a second later the lights go out as system reboots. The screen does nothing until it boots from the crash. Issue persists on Intel, Hybrid, Nvidia GPU performance modes as well as using the Nouveau driver.

Tested on:

- Ubuntu 22.04 Gnome Wayland
- Pop!_OS 22.04 Gnome Wayland
- Kubuntu 22.04 KDE Plasma Wayland, X11
- Manjaro 23 KDE Plasma Wayland, X11
- KDE Neon Unstable with Plasma 6.0 Wayland

Have tried Nvidia drivers 470 and 545

Have tried disabling nvidia-suspend nvidia-hibernate nvidia-resume [(seems like a common fix)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1335689/ubuntu-20-04-lts-can-not-resume-after-suspending)

[Also tried this split lock detection fix after seeing the log below](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1356884/why-is-x86-split-lock-detection-spamming-my-syslog-when-steam-is-running)

Here's a section of journalctl log from ubuntu 22 (I think from sleep started to crash):

```
Feb 25 21:24:05 AORUS-15-XE4 ModemManager[991]: <info>  [sleep-monitor-systemd] system is about to suspend
Feb 25 21:24:05 AORUS-15-XE4 NetworkManager[921]: <info>  [1708914245.2758] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Feb 25 21:24:05 AORUS-15-XE4 NetworkManager[921]: <info>  [1708914245.2760] device (enp47s0): state change: unavailable -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 25 21:24:05 AORUS-15-XE4 NetworkManager[921]: <info>  [1708914245.2858] device (wlp46s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 25 21:24:05 AORUS-15-XE4 NetworkManager[921]: <info>  [1708914245.3224] device (p2p-dev-wlp46s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 25 21:24:05 AORUS-15-XE4 wpa_supplicant[961]: p2p-dev-wlp46s0: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Feb 25 21:24:05 AORUS-15-XE4 NetworkManager[921]: <info>  [1708914245.3226] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Feb 25 21:24:05 AORUS-15-XE4 wpa_supplicant[961]: p2p-dev-wlp46s0: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Feb 25 21:24:05 AORUS-15-XE4 wpa_supplicant[961]: nl80211: deinit ifname=p2p-dev-wlp46s0 disabled_11b_rates=0
Feb 25 21:24:05 AORUS-15-XE4 wpa_supplicant[961]: wlp46s0: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Feb 25 21:24:05 AORUS-15-XE4 wpa_supplicant[961]: wlp46s0: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Feb 25 21:24:05 AORUS-15-XE4 wpa_supplicant[961]: nl80211: deinit ifname=wlp46s0 disabled_11b_rates=0
Feb 25 21:24:10 AORUS-15-XE4 systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Feb 25 21:24:10 AORUS-15-XE4 systemd[1]: Starting Record successful boot for GRUB...
Feb 25 21:24:10 AORUS-15-XE4 systemd[1]: Starting NVIDIA system suspend actions...
Feb 25 21:24:10 AORUS-15-XE4 suspend[6929]: nvidia-suspend.service
Feb 25 21:24:10 AORUS-15-XE4 logger[6929]: <13>Feb 25 21:24:10 suspend: nvidia-suspend.service
Feb 25 21:24:10 AORUS-15-XE4 systemd[1]: grub-common.service: Deactivated successfully.
Feb 25 21:24:10 AORUS-15-XE4 systemd[1]: Finished Record successful boot for GRUB.
Feb 25 21:24:10 AORUS-15-XE4 systemd[1]: Starting GRUB failed boot detection...
Feb 25 21:24:10 AORUS-15-XE4 systemd[1]: grub-initrd-fallback.service: Deactivated successfully.
Feb 25 21:24:10 AORUS-15-XE4 systemd[1]: Finished GRUB failed boot detection.
Feb 25 21:24:12 AORUS-15-XE4 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2384]: (**) Option "fd" "46"
Feb 25 21:24:12 AORUS-15-XE4 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2384]: (II) event4  - Power Button: device removed
Feb 25 21:24:12 AORUS-15-XE4 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2384]: (**) Option "fd" "49"
Feb 25 21:24:12 AORUS-15-XE4 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2384]: (II) event22 - Video Bus: device removed
Feb 25 21:24:12 AORUS-15-XE4 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2384]: (**) Option "fd" "50"
Feb 25 21:24:12 AORUS-15-XE4 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2384]: (II) event20 - Video Bus: device removed
Feb 25 21:24:12 AORUS-15-XE4 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2384]: (**) Option "fd" "51"
Feb 25 21:24:12 AORUS-15-XE4 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2384]: (II) event1  - Sleep Button: device removed
Feb 25 21:24:12 AORUS-15-XE4 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2384]: (**) Option "fd" "52"
Feb 25 21:24:12 AORUS-15-XE4 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2384]: (II) event3  - Power Button: device removed
Feb 25 21:24:12 AORUS-15-XE4 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2384]: (**) Option "fd" "53"
Feb 25 21:24:12 AORUS-15-XE4 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2384]: (II) event2  - Sleep Button: device removed
Feb 25 21:24:12 AORUS-15-XE4 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2384]: (**) Option "fd" "54"
Feb 25 21:24:12 AORUS-15-XE4 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2384]: (II) event8  - GIGABYTE USB-HID Keyboard: device removed
Feb 25 21:24:12 AORUS-15-XE4 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2384]: (**) Option "fd" "55"
Feb 25 21:24:12 AORUS-15-XE4 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2384]: (II) event9  - GIGABYTE USB-HID Keyboard Mouse: device removed
Feb 25 21:24:12 AORUS-15-XE4 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2384]: (**) Option "fd" "56"
Feb 25 21:24:12 AORUS-15-XE4 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2384]: (II) event10 - GIGABYTE USB-HID Keyboard System Control: device removed
Feb 25 21:24:12 AORUS-15-XE4 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2384]: (**) Option "fd" "57"
Feb 25 21:24:12 AORUS-15-XE4 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2384]: (**) Option "fd" "58"
Feb 25 21:24:12 AORUS-15-XE4 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2384]: (II) event16 - GIGABYTE USB-HID Keyboard: device removed
Feb 25 21:24:12 AORUS-15-XE4 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2384]: (**) Option "fd" "59"
Feb 25 21:24:12 AORUS-15-XE4 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2384]: (II) event18 - GIGABYTE USB-HID Keyboard Wireless Radio Control: device removed
Feb 25 21:24:12 AORUS-15-XE4 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2384]: (**) Option "fd" "60"
Feb 25 21:24:12 AORUS-15-XE4 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2384]: (II) event19 - Generic USB Audio Consumer Control: device removed
Feb 25 21:24:12 AORUS-15-XE4 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2384]: (**) Option "fd" "61"
Feb 25 21:24:12 AORUS-15-XE4 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2384]: (II) event21 - Generic USB Audio: device removed
Feb 25 21:24:12 AORUS-15-XE4 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2384]: (**) Option "fd" "62"
Feb 25 21:24:12 AORUS-15-XE4 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2384]: (II) event6  - ELAN0A02:00 04F3:31EA Mouse: device removed
Feb 25 21:24:12 AORUS-15-XE4 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2384]: (**) Option "fd" "63"
Feb 25 21:24:12 AORUS-15-XE4 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2384]: (II) event7  - ELAN0A02:00 04F3:31EA Touchpad: device removed
Feb 25 21:24:12 AORUS-15-XE4 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2384]: (**) Option "fd" "64"
Feb 25 21:24:12 AORUS-15-XE4 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2384]: (II) event5  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: device removed
Feb 25 21:24:12 AORUS-15-XE4 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2384]: (**) Option "fd" "57"
Feb 25 21:24:12 AORUS-15-XE4 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2384]: (II) event12 - GIGABYTE USB-HID Keyboard Consumer Control: device removed
Feb 25 21:24:12 AORUS-15-XE4 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2384]: (**) Option "fd" "91"
Feb 25 21:24:12 AORUS-15-XE4 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2384]: (**) Option "fd" "91"
Feb 25 21:24:12 AORUS-15-XE4 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2384]: (II) event28 - Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3: device removed
Feb 25 21:24:12 AORUS-15-XE4 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2384]: (II) AIGLX: Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch
Feb 25 21:24:12 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: rfkill: input handler enabled
Feb 25 21:24:12 AORUS-15-XE4 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2384]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:92
Feb 25 21:24:12 AORUS-15-XE4 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2384]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:66
Feb 25 21:24:12 AORUS-15-XE4 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2384]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:85
Feb 25 21:24:12 AORUS-15-XE4 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2384]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:74
Feb 25 21:24:12 AORUS-15-XE4 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2384]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:68
Feb 25 21:24:12 AORUS-15-XE4 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2384]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:84
Feb 25 21:24:12 AORUS-15-XE4 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2384]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:80
Feb 25 21:24:12 AORUS-15-XE4 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2384]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:82
Feb 25 21:24:12 AORUS-15-XE4 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2384]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:72
Feb 25 21:24:12 AORUS-15-XE4 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2384]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:69
Feb 25 21:24:12 AORUS-15-XE4 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2384]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:73
Feb 25 21:24:12 AORUS-15-XE4 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2384]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:83
Feb 25 21:24:12 AORUS-15-XE4 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2384]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:86
Feb 25 21:24:12 AORUS-15-XE4 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2384]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:76
Feb 25 21:24:12 AORUS-15-XE4 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2384]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:65
Feb 25 21:24:12 AORUS-15-XE4 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2384]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:71
Feb 25 21:24:12 AORUS-15-XE4 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2384]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:70
Feb 25 21:24:12 AORUS-15-XE4 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2384]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:67
Feb 25 21:24:13 AORUS-15-XE4 systemd[1]: nvidia-suspend.service: Deactivated successfully.
Feb 25 21:24:13 AORUS-15-XE4 systemd[1]: Finished NVIDIA system suspend actions.
Feb 25 21:24:13 AORUS-15-XE4 systemd[1]: Starting System Suspend...
Feb 25 21:24:13 AORUS-15-XE4 systemd-sleep[6945]: Entering sleep state 'suspend'...
-- Boot 8faa9d8609e24a008be40e5459c5f035 --
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: microcode: updated early: 0x419 -> 0x430, date = 2023-06-07
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: Linux version 6.5.0-21-generic (buildd@lcy02-amd64-091) (x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.38) #21~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Feb  9 13:32:52 UTC 2 (Ubuntu 6.5.0-21.21~22.04.1-generic 6.5.8)
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-21-generic root=UUID=cb20773d-847c-45a4-af6f-4d16b7228064 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: KERNEL supported cpus:
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel:   Intel GenuineIntel
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel:   AMD AuthenticAMD
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel:   Hygon HygonGenuine
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel:   Centaur CentaurHauls
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel:   zhaoxin   Shanghai  
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: x86/split lock detection: #AC: crashing the kernel on kernel split_locks and warning on user-space split_locks
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009dfff] usable
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000009e000-0x000000000009efff] reserved
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000009f000-0x000000000009ffff] usable
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000000a0000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x000000003b57dfff] usable
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000003b57e000-0x0000000041b7bfff] reserved
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000041b7c000-0x0000000041c68fff] ACPI data
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000041c69000-0x0000000041dd3fff] ACPI NVS
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000041dd4000-0x00000000427fefff] reserved
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000427ff000-0x00000000427fffff] usable
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000042800000-0x00000000491fffff] reserved
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000049e00000-0x00000000503fffff] reserved
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000c0000000-0x00000000cfffffff] reserved
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fe000000-0x00000000fe010fff] reserved
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fec00000-0x00000000fec00fff] reserved
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fed00000-0x00000000fed00fff] reserved
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fed20000-0x00000000fed7ffff] reserved
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fee00000-0x00000000fee00fff] reserved
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000ff000000-0x00000000ffffffff] reserved
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x00000008afbfffff] usable
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: NX (Execute Disable) protection: active
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: e820: update [mem 0x3421b018-0x3423f657] usable ==> usable
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: e820: update [mem 0x3421b018-0x3423f657] usable ==> usable
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: extended physical RAM map:
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: reserve setup_data: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009dfff] usable
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: reserve setup_data: [mem 0x000000000009e000-0x000000000009efff] reserved
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: reserve setup_data: [mem 0x000000000009f000-0x000000000009ffff] usable
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: reserve setup_data: [mem 0x00000000000a0000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: reserve setup_data: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x000000003421b017] usable
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: reserve setup_data: [mem 0x000000003421b018-0x000000003423f657] usable
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: reserve setup_data: [mem 0x000000003423f658-0x000000003b57dfff] usable
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: reserve setup_data: [mem 0x000000003b57e000-0x0000000041b7bfff] reserved
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: reserve setup_data: [mem 0x0000000041b7c000-0x0000000041c68fff] ACPI data
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: reserve setup_data: [mem 0x0000000041c69000-0x0000000041dd3fff] ACPI NVS
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: reserve setup_data: [mem 0x0000000041dd4000-0x00000000427fefff] reserved
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: reserve setup_data: [mem 0x00000000427ff000-0x00000000427fffff] usable
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: reserve setup_data: [mem 0x0000000042800000-0x00000000491fffff] reserved
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: reserve setup_data: [mem 0x0000000049e00000-0x00000000503fffff] reserved
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: reserve setup_data: [mem 0x00000000c0000000-0x00000000cfffffff] reserved
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: reserve setup_data: [mem 0x00000000fe000000-0x00000000fe010fff] reserved
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: reserve setup_data: [mem 0x00000000fec00000-0x00000000fec00fff] reserved
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: reserve setup_data: [mem 0x00000000fed00000-0x00000000fed00fff] reserved
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: reserve setup_data: [mem 0x00000000fed20000-0x00000000fed7ffff] reserved
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: reserve setup_data: [mem 0x00000000fee00000-0x00000000fee00fff] reserved
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: reserve setup_data: [mem 0x00000000ff000000-0x00000000ffffffff] reserved
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: reserve setup_data: [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x00000008afbfffff] usable
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: efi: EFI v2.8 by American Megatrends
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: efi: ACPI=0x41c68000 ACPI 2.0=0x41c68014 SMBIOS=0x4258e000 SMBIOS 3.0=0x4258d000 MEMATTR=0x36a94018 ESRT=0x36d44d98 MOKvar=0x425c9000 RNG=0x41bac018 
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: random: crng init done
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: efi: Remove mem75: MMIO range=[0xc0000000-0xcfffffff] (256MB) from e820 map
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: e820: remove [mem 0xc0000000-0xcfffffff] reserved
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: efi: Not removing mem76: MMIO range=[0xfe000000-0xfe010fff] (68KB) from e820 map
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: efi: Not removing mem77: MMIO range=[0xfec00000-0xfec00fff] (4KB) from e820 map
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: efi: Not removing mem78: MMIO range=[0xfed00000-0xfed00fff] (4KB) from e820 map
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: efi: Not removing mem80: MMIO range=[0xfee00000-0xfee00fff] (4KB) from e820 map
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: efi: Remove mem81: MMIO range=[0xff000000-0xffffffff] (16MB) from e820 map
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: e820: remove [mem 0xff000000-0xffffffff] reserved
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: secureboot: Secure boot disabled
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: SMBIOS 3.4.0 present.
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: DMI: GIGABYTE AORUS 15 XE4/AORUS 15 XE4, BIOS FB08 03/07/2022
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: tsc: Detected 2700.000 MHz processor
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: tsc: Detected 2688.000 MHz TSC
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: e820: update [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff] usable ==> reserved
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: e820: remove [mem 0x000a0000-0x000fffff] usable
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: last_pfn = 0x8afc00 max_arch_pfn = 0x400000000
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: MTRR map: 5 entries (3 fixed + 2 variable; max 23), built from 10 variable MTRRs
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: x86/PAT: Configuration [0-7]: WB  WC  UC- UC  WB  WP  UC- WT  
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: last_pfn = 0x42800 max_arch_pfn = 0x400000000
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: esrt: Reserving ESRT space from 0x0000000036d44d98 to 0x0000000036d44e70.
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: e820: update [mem 0x36d44000-0x36d44fff] usable ==> reserved
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: Using GB pages for direct mapping
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: Incomplete global flushes, disabling PCID
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: secureboot: Secure boot disabled
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: RAMDISK: [mem 0x2cb70000-0x30e60fff]
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: Early table checksum verification disabled
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: RSDP 0x0000000041C68014 000024 (v02 GBT   )
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: XSDT 0x0000000041C67728 00012C (v01 GBT    GBTUACPI 01072009 AMI  01000013)
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: FACP 0x0000000041C64000 000114 (v06 GBT    GBTUACPI 01072009 AMI  01000013)
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: DSDT 0x0000000041BF7000 06CE53 (v02 GBT    GBTUACPI 01072009 INTL 20200717)
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: FACS 0x0000000041DD2000 000040
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: SSDT 0x0000000041C65000 001459 (v02 DptfTb DptfTabl 00001000 INTL 20200717)
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: FIDT 0x0000000041BF6000 00009C (v01 GBT    GBTUACPI 01072009 AMI  00010013)
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: MSDM 0x0000000041BF5000 000055 (v03 GBT    GBTUACPI 01072009 AMI  01000013)
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: SLIC 0x0000000041BF4000 000176 (v01 GBT    GBTUACPI 01072009 AMI  01000013)
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: SSDT 0x0000000041BF3000 00038C (v02 PmaxDv Pmax_Dev 00000001 INTL 20200717)
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: SSDT 0x0000000041BED000 005D0B (v02 CpuRef CpuSsdt  00003000 INTL 20200717)
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: SSDT 0x0000000041BEA000 002AA1 (v02 SaSsdt SaSsdt   00003000 INTL 20200717)
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: SSDT 0x0000000041BE6000 0033D3 (v02 INTEL  IgfxSsdt 00003000 INTL 20200717)
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: SSDT 0x0000000041BD8000 00D39F (v02 INTEL  TcssSsdt 00001000 INTL 20200717)
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: HPET 0x0000000041BD7000 000038 (v01 GBT    GBTUACPI 01072009 AMI  01000013)
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: APIC 0x0000000041BD6000 0001DC (v05 GBT    GBTUACPI 01072009 AMI  01000013)
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: MCFG 0x0000000041BD5000 00003C (v01 GBT    GBTUACPI 01072009 AMI  01000013)
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: SSDT 0x0000000041BCB000 009778 (v02 GBT    AdlP_Rvp 00001000 INTL 20200717)
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: SSDT 0x0000000041BC9000 001F1A (v02 GBT    Ther_Rvp 00001000 INTL 20200717)
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: UEFI 0x0000000041D15000 000048 (v01 GBT    GBTUACPI 01072009 AMI  01000013)
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: NHLT 0x0000000041BC8000 00002D (v00 GBT    GBTUACPI 01072009 AMI  01000013)
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: LPIT 0x0000000041BC7000 0000CC (v01 GBT    GBTUACPI 01072009 AMI  01000013)
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: SSDT 0x0000000041BC3000 002A83 (v02 GBT    PtidDevc 00001000 INTL 20200717)
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: SSDT 0x0000000041BC0000 002357 (v02 GBT    TbtTypeC 00000000 INTL 20200717)
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: DBGP 0x0000000041BBF000 000034 (v01 GBT    GBTUACPI 01072009 AMI  01000013)
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: DBG2 0x0000000041BBE000 000054 (v00 GBT    GBTUACPI 01072009 AMI  01000013)
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: DMAR 0x0000000041BBD000 000088 (v02 INTEL  EDK2     00000002      01000013)
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: SSDT 0x0000000041BBC000 0008D1 (v02 INTEL  xh_adlLP 00000000 INTL 20200717)
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: SSDT 0x0000000041BB8000 003AEA (v02 SocGpe SocGpe   00003000 INTL 20200717)
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: SSDT 0x0000000041BB4000 0035A2 (v02 SocCmn SocCmn   00003000 INTL 20200717)
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: SSDT 0x0000000041BB3000 000457 (v02 HgRef  HgRpSsdt 00001000 INTL 20200717)
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: SSDT 0x0000000041BB2000 000144 (v02 Intel  ADebTabl 00001000 INTL 20200717)
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: BGRT 0x0000000041BB1000 000038 (v01 GBT    GBTUACPI 01072009 AMI  00010013)
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: SSDT 0x0000000041BAF000 001B6A (v01 OptRf2 Opt2Tabl 00001000 INTL 20200717)
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: PHAT 0x0000000041BAE000 00062D (v01 GBT    GBTUACPI 00000005 MSFT 0100000D)
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: WSMT 0x0000000041BC6000 000028 (v01 GBT    GBTUACPI 01072009 AMI  00010013)
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: FPDT 0x0000000041BAD000 000044 (v01 GBT    A M I    01072009 AMI  01000013)
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: Reserving FACP table memory at [mem 0x41c64000-0x41c64113]
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: Reserving DSDT table memory at [mem 0x41bf7000-0x41c63e52]
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: Reserving FACS table memory at [mem 0x41dd2000-0x41dd203f]
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: Reserving SSDT table memory at [mem 0x41c65000-0x41c66458]
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: Reserving FIDT table memory at [mem 0x41bf6000-0x41bf609b]
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: Reserving MSDM table memory at [mem 0x41bf5000-0x41bf5054]
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: Reserving SLIC table memory at [mem 0x41bf4000-0x41bf4175]
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: Reserving SSDT table memory at [mem 0x41bf3000-0x41bf338b]
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: Reserving SSDT table memory at [mem 0x41bed000-0x41bf2d0a]
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: Reserving SSDT table memory at [mem 0x41bea000-0x41becaa0]
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: Reserving SSDT table memory at [mem 0x41be6000-0x41be93d2]
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: Reserving SSDT table memory at [mem 0x41bd8000-0x41be539e]
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: Reserving HPET table memory at [mem 0x41bd7000-0x41bd7037]
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: Reserving APIC table memory at [mem 0x41bd6000-0x41bd61db]
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: Reserving MCFG table memory at [mem 0x41bd5000-0x41bd503b]
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: Reserving SSDT table memory at [mem 0x41bcb000-0x41bd4777]
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: Reserving SSDT table memory at [mem 0x41bc9000-0x41bcaf19]
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: Reserving UEFI table memory at [mem 0x41d15000-0x41d15047]
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: Reserving NHLT table memory at [mem 0x41bc8000-0x41bc802c]
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: Reserving LPIT table memory at [mem 0x41bc7000-0x41bc70cb]
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: Reserving SSDT table memory at [mem 0x41bc3000-0x41bc5a82]
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: Reserving SSDT table memory at [mem 0x41bc0000-0x41bc2356]
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: Reserving DBGP table memory at [mem 0x41bbf000-0x41bbf033]
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: Reserving DBG2 table memory at [mem 0x41bbe000-0x41bbe053]
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: Reserving DMAR table memory at [mem 0x41bbd000-0x41bbd087]
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: Reserving SSDT table memory at [mem 0x41bbc000-0x41bbc8d0]
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: Reserving SSDT table memory at [mem 0x41bb8000-0x41bbbae9]
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: Reserving SSDT table memory at [mem 0x41bb4000-0x41bb75a1]
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: Reserving SSDT table memory at [mem 0x41bb3000-0x41bb3456]
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: Reserving SSDT table memory at [mem 0x41bb2000-0x41bb2143]
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: Reserving BGRT table memory at [mem 0x41bb1000-0x41bb1037]
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: Reserving SSDT table memory at [mem 0x41baf000-0x41bb0b69]
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: Reserving PHAT table memory at [mem 0x41bae000-0x41bae62c]
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: Reserving WSMT table memory at [mem 0x41bc6000-0x41bc6027]
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: Reserving FPDT table memory at [mem 0x41bad000-0x41bad043]
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: No NUMA configuration found
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: Faking a node at [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x00000008afbfffff]
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: NODE_DATA(0) allocated [mem 0x8afbd5000-0x8afbfffff]
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: Zone ranges:
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel:   DMA      [mem 0x0000000000001000-0x0000000000ffffff]
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel:   DMA32    [mem 0x0000000001000000-0x00000000ffffffff]
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel:   Normal   [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x00000008afbfffff]
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel:   Device   empty
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: Movable zone start for each node
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: Early memory node ranges
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel:   node   0: [mem 0x0000000000001000-0x000000000009dfff]
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel:   node   0: [mem 0x000000000009f000-0x000000000009ffff]
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel:   node   0: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x000000003b57dfff]
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel:   node   0: [mem 0x00000000427ff000-0x00000000427fffff]
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel:   node   0: [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x00000008afbfffff]
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: Initmem setup node 0 [mem 0x0000000000001000-0x00000008afbfffff]
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: On node 0, zone DMA: 1 pages in unavailable ranges
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: On node 0, zone DMA: 1 pages in unavailable ranges
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: On node 0, zone DMA: 96 pages in unavailable ranges
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: On node 0, zone DMA32: 29313 pages in unavailable ranges
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: On node 0, zone Normal: 22528 pages in unavailable ranges
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: On node 0, zone Normal: 1024 pages in unavailable ranges
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: Reserving Intel graphics memory at [mem 0x4c800000-0x503fffff]
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: PM-Timer IO Port: 0x1808
Feb 25 21:24:59 AORUS-15-XE4 kernel: ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x01] high edge lint[0x1])
```

Any thoughts on what you would try next? Are there other logs somewhere that might show if the kernel has more errors or something?

Comment: Update your BIOS to the latest version then try kernel 6.7.7 with and without NVIDIA drivers. If it still crashes, file a bug report here: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/ In reality distros aren't so different.

Comment: BIOS is latest. I was only able to try 6.7.4 and 6.8.0 experimental on manjaro but neither made a difference. Would that be enough or should I try 6.7.7 specifically? I couldn't find a great way to force install 6.7.7.

Comment: 6.7.4 or 6.7.7 doesn't make a lot of difference, so, you could just file a bug report.

Comment: Will do. What would be a good log to attach to the report? Not sure if what I have is very helpful.

Comment: At the very least attach `dmesg`  (on boot, i.e. including the entire boot sequence) and `lspci`.

Comment: Great, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are hitting a bug in the nouveau kernel-mode driver that might get activated even with the proprietary nvidia driver installed, try adding

```
 nouveau.modeset=0
```

to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` in the `/etc/default/grub` file, after that run:

```
sudo update-grub
sudo reboot
```